# Jetpack Compose: How to draw a path / line like this

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

I want to achieve something like the below picture using canvas.
How can I achieve something like this?

[image]

Is there some reference that I can look up?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://dev.to/tkuenneth/drawing-and-painting-in-jetpack-compose-1-2okl) article will help you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can draw it with Path and cubicTo.

```
path.cubicTo(x1 = x1, y1 = y1, x2 = x2, y2 = y2, x3 = x3, y3 = y3)
```

For a dashed effect, you should use:

```
drawPath(
            color = Color.Green,
            path = path,
            style = Stroke(
                width = 3.dp.toPx(),
                pathEffect = PathEffect.dashPathEffect(floatArrayOf(10f, 10f))
            )
        )
```

With the sample below, I think it will make it easy to understand how the cubic changes by changing the start(x0, y0), end(x3, y3) and control points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2).

[image]

```
@Composable
fun DrawCubic() {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
    ) {

        val density = LocalDensity.current.density

        val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
        val screenWidth = configuration.screenWidthDp.dp

        val screenWidthInPx = screenWidth.value * density

        // (x0, y0) is initial coordinate where path is moved with path.moveTo(x0,y0)
        var x0 by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
        var y0 by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

        /*
        Adds a cubic bezier segment that curves from the current point(x0,y0) to the
        given point (x3, y3), using the control points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2).
     */
        var x1 by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
        var y1 by remember { mutableStateOf(screenWidthInPx) }
        var x2 by remember { mutableStateOf(screenWidthInPx/2) }
        var y2 by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

        var x3 by remember { mutableStateOf(screenWidthInPx) }
        var y3 by remember { mutableStateOf(screenWidthInPx/2) }

        val path = remember { Path() }
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(8.dp)
                .shadow(1.dp)
                .background(Color.White)
                .size(screenWidth, screenWidth/2)
        ) {
            path.reset()
            path.moveTo(x0, y0)
            path.cubicTo(x1 = x1, y1 = y1, x2 = x2, y2 = y2, x3 = x3, y3 = y3)


            drawPath(
                color = Color.Green,
                path = path,
                style = Stroke(
                    width = 3.dp.toPx(),
                    pathEffect = PathEffect.dashPathEffect(floatArrayOf(10f, 10f))
                )
            )

            // Draw Control Points on screen
            drawPoints(
                listOf(Offset(x1, y1), Offset(x2, y2)),
                color = Color.Green,
                pointMode = PointMode.Points,
                cap = StrokeCap.Round,
                strokeWidth = 40f
            )
        }

        Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 20.dp)) {

            Text(text = "X0: ${x0.roundToInt()}")
            Slider(
                value = x0,
                onValueChange = { x0 = it },
                valueRange = 0f..screenWidthInPx,
            )

            Text(text = "Y0: ${y0.roundToInt()}")
            Slider(
                value = y0,
                onValueChange = { y0 = it },
                valueRange = 0f..screenWidthInPx,
            )

            Text(text = "X1: ${x1.roundToInt()}")
            Slider(
                value = x1,
                onValueChange = { x1 = it },
                valueRange = 0f..screenWidthInPx,
            )

            Text(text = "Y1: ${y1.roundToInt()}")
            Slider(
                value = y1,
                onValueChange = { y1 = it },
                valueRange = 0f..screenWidthInPx,
            )

            Text(text = "X2: ${x2.roundToInt()}")
            Slider(
                value = x2,
                onValueChange = { x2 = it },
                valueRange = 0f..screenWidthInPx,
            )

            Text(text = "Y2: ${y2.roundToInt()}")
            Slider(
                value = y2,
                onValueChange = { y2 = it },
                valueRange = 0f..screenWidthInPx,
            )

            Text(text = "X3: ${x3.roundToInt()}")
            Slider(
                value = x3,
                onValueChange = { x3 = it },
                valueRange = 0f..screenWidthInPx,
            )

            Text(text = "Y3: ${y3.roundToInt()}")
            Slider(
                value = y3,
                onValueChange = { y3 = it },
                valueRange = 0f..screenWidthInPx,
            )
        }
    }
}
```

More about quads, cubics, paths, Blend modes and Canvas is available in [this tutorial](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials#graphics).

Comment: I wouldn't have recommended this, sir, for other than academic purposes. Not practical much, you concur?

Comment: You draw the path OP asked with a cubic. And for the arrow path you can add another path at position of (x3, y3). And as i mentioned in answer this answer helps you get how cubic changes when you change control points and start and end points of cubic.

Comment: My bad, didn't realise the actual code to draw the cubic is almost the same as the method I illustrated. Rather better, might even say. Got confused by the rest of the codebase so I thought ten lines of code were used to render just the cubic... Lazy reading, sorry.

Comment: Sliders are for demonstrating how control points change a cubic

Comment: Yes, I got that, I understand the code. Previously I just glanced at it, looking at the variables made me think 10 vars were required to render the shape, so I thought it'd be better to go for the hard-coded path approach. I have read the entire solution, and the variables were found to be used for enabling dynamic altering of the control points.

Comment: Yes, you are right. OP asks for a reference he/she could look up so i posted not only how you draw a bezier curve but how points you set it with changes curve. Bezier curves can be complicated without a reference, that's why answer is a bit long. Also i draw control points to visualize where they actually are when you change the curve. Have a good day everyone.✌️

Comment: I was about to propose a referencing duel, I guess I can come up with a little under 950 references to put in my answer regarding this, but yeah... good day to you too sir ✌

Comment: thank you for helping me to understand how canvas works Thracian.

Comment: awesome! Such a beautiful cubic you have )

Answer (score 6):

As a general alternative to [Thracian's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73468745/jetpack-compose-how-to-draw-a-path-line-like-this/73469065#73469065), which uses the programmatic method to build the path in real-time, for *complex* shapes/vectors, this is the less painful method:

```
val pathData = "M 60,60 L 60,0 L 50,10 L 60,0 L 70,10"

Canvas() {
  drawPath(
    path = PathParser.createPathFromPathData(pathData)).asComposePath()
  )
}
```

This, for example, draws an arrow on the screen. All you need is the pathData for your line/vector. Then it is as simple as assigning that to the `pathData` variable, as illustrated above.

Also, remember that the `PathParser` here is the one from `androidx.graphics` package, not the Compsose Path Parser.

Comment: if you have more references about Canvas, paths, cubics or quads please share them. It would help everyone a lot. It's really hard to come by any good sources about Canvas.

Comment: Feel free to chime in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692795/define-custom-boundaries-for-a-composable

Comment: Re *"Compsose"*: Do you mean *"Compose"*?

Comment: No, Pete. I say what I mean. I was talking about ***Compsose***. It's a... a framework library, that was built by ... uh, Dr. Thracian here.