# Jetpack Compose - CardView with Arc Shape on border

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, cardview

I'm trying to achieve the below card view arc shape on the card view border/stroke.
Already tried to search on google but didn't find any relevant answer that suits with requirements.

Any lead or help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: you can customize this by adding a custom shape via a path. check this https://juliensalvi.medium.com/custom-shape-with-jetpack-compose-1cb48a991d42

Comment: just add https://medium.com/swlh/curved-cut-out-bottom-navigation-with-animation-in-android-c630c867958c the bottom curve is what you need to customize. its a bezier curve.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answer from Cirilo Bido and Raghunandan is good place to start, you round corners of rectangle with `arcTo`  but you can't draw curved edges on top of clipped out shape. You need to use `cubicTo` to draw rounded edge and curve to clip out bottom shape

```
   val shape = GenericShape {size: Size, layoutDirection: LayoutDirection ->
                            // draw cubic on left and right sides for button space
                            cubicTo()
                        }
```

[image]

You can check out this answer for drawing with cubic to. By combining both you can draw that path.

[Jetpack Compose: How to draw a path / line like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73468745/jetpack-compose-how-to-draw-a-path-line-like-this/73469065#73469065)

I created this path based on article shared by
Raghunandan initially, even though that is amazing answer for animating BottomBar it doesn't create a rounded shape if you look closely, at the bottom it's creating a triangular shape at the bottom instead of rounded one and shape OP requires and in article is also different.

So i used sliders to create bezier from the link i shared above. It's available as [tutorial here](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials#6-1-3-canvas-paths) too. Still it can be tweaked to more precise shape if you wish to.

[image]

I used x0, y0 as reference point to set control points and created this Path extension function.

```
fun Path.roundedRectanglePath(
    size: Size,
    cornerRadius: Float,
    fabRadius: Float,
) {

    val centerX = size.width / 2
    val x0 = centerX - fabRadius * 1.15f
    val y0 = 0f

    // offset of the first control point (top part)
    val topControlX = x0 + fabRadius * .5f
    val topControlY = y0

    // offset of the second control point (bottom part)
    val bottomControlX = x0
    val bottomControlY = y0 + fabRadius

    // first curve
    // set the starting point of the curve (P2)
    val firstCurveStart = Offset(x0, y0)

    // set the end point for the first curve (P3)
    val firstCurveEnd = Offset(centerX, fabRadius * 1f)

    // set the first control point (C1)
    val firstCurveControlPoint1 = Offset(
        x = topControlX,
        y = topControlY
    )

    // set the second control point (C2)
    val firstCurveControlPoint2 = Offset(
        x = bottomControlX,
        y = bottomControlY
    )


    // second curve
    // end of first curve and start of second curve is the same (P3)
    val secondCurveStart = Offset(
        x = firstCurveEnd.x,
        y = firstCurveEnd.y
    )

    // end of the second curve (P4)
    val secondCurveEnd = Offset(
        x = centerX + fabRadius * 1.15f,
        y = 0f
    )

    // set the first control point of second curve (C4)
    val secondCurveControlPoint1 = Offset(
        x = secondCurveStart.x + fabRadius,
        y = bottomControlY
    )

    // set the second control point (C3)
    val secondCurveControlPoint2 = Offset(
        x = secondCurveEnd.x - fabRadius / 2,
        y = topControlY
    )


    // Top left arc
    val radius = cornerRadius * 2

    arcTo(
        rect = Rect(
            left = 0f,
            top = 0f,
            right = radius,
            bottom = radius
        ),
        startAngleDegrees = 180.0f,
        sweepAngleDegrees = 90.0f,
        forceMoveTo = false
    )



    lineTo(x = firstCurveStart.x, y = firstCurveStart.y)

    // bezier curve with (P2, C1, C2, P3)
    cubicTo(
        x1 = firstCurveControlPoint1.x,
        y1 = firstCurveControlPoint1.y,
        x2 = firstCurveControlPoint2.x,
        y2 = firstCurveControlPoint2.y,
        x3 = firstCurveEnd.x,
        y3 = firstCurveEnd.y
    )

    // bezier curve with (P3, C4, C3, P4)
    cubicTo(
        x1 = secondCurveControlPoint1.x,
        y1 = secondCurveControlPoint1.y,
        x2 = secondCurveControlPoint2.x,
        y2 = secondCurveControlPoint2.y,
        x3 = secondCurveEnd.x,
        y3 = secondCurveEnd.y
    )

    lineTo(x = size.width - cornerRadius, y = 0f)

    // Top right arc
    arcTo(
        rect = Rect(
            left = size.width - radius,
            top = 0f,
            right = size.width,
            bottom = radius
        ),
        startAngleDegrees = -90.0f,
        sweepAngleDegrees = 90.0f,
        forceMoveTo = false
    )

    lineTo(x = 0f + size.width, y = size.height - cornerRadius)

    // Bottom right arc
    arcTo(
        rect = Rect(
            left = size.width - radius,
            top = size.height - radius,
            right = size.width,
            bottom = size.height
        ),
        startAngleDegrees = 0f,
        sweepAngleDegrees = 90.0f,
        forceMoveTo = false
    )

    lineTo(x = cornerRadius, y = size.height)

    // Bottom left arc
    arcTo(
        rect = Rect(
            left = 0f,
            top = size.height - radius,
            right = radius,
            bottom = size.height
        ),
        startAngleDegrees = 90.0f,
        sweepAngleDegrees = 90.0f,
        forceMoveTo = false
    )

    lineTo(x = 0f, y = cornerRadius)
    close()
}
```

Composable that uses this shape

```
@Composable
private fun CustomArcShape(
    modifier: Modifier,
    elevation: Dp = 4.dp,
    color: Color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface,
    contentColor: Color = contentColorFor(color),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {

    val diameter = 60.dp
    val radiusDp = diameter / 2

    val cornerRadiusDp = 10.dp

    val density = LocalDensity.current
    val cutoutRadius = density.run { radiusDp.toPx() }
    val cornerRadius = density.run { cornerRadiusDp.toPx() }

    val shape = remember {
        GenericShape { size: Size, layoutDirection: LayoutDirection ->
            this.roundedRectanglePath(
                size = size,
                cornerRadius = cornerRadius,
                fabRadius = cutoutRadius * 2
            )
        }
    }

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(diameter / 2))

    Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.TopCenter) {
        FloatingActionButton(
            shape = CircleShape,
            containerColor = Color(0xffD32F2F),
            modifier = Modifier
                .offset(y = -diameter / 5)
                .size(diameter)
                .drawBehind {
                    drawCircle(
                        Color.Red.copy(.5f),
                        radius = 1.3f * size.width / 2
                    )

                    drawCircle(
                        Color.Red.copy(.3f),
                        radius = 1.5f * size.width / 2
                    )

                }
                .align(Alignment.TopCenter),
            onClick = { /*TODO*/ }
        ) {
            Icon(
                tint = Color.White,
                imageVector = Icons.Filled.Close,
                contentDescription = "Close"
            )
        }

        Surface(
            modifier = modifier,
            shape = shape,
            shadowElevation = elevation,
            color = color,
            contentColor = contentColor
        ) {
            Column {
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(diameter))
                content()

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And demonstration

```
@Composable
private fun CustomArcShapeSample() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {

        CustomArcShape(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(10.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(250.dp)
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                Text(
                    "Payment Failed",
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
                Text("Sorry !", fontSize = 24.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
                Text("Your transfer to bank failed", color = Color.LightGray)
            }
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(40.dp))

        CustomArcShape(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(10.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(250.dp)
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .border(1.dp, Color.Green),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                Text(
                    "Payment Failed",
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
                Text("Sorry !", fontSize = 24.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
                Text("Your transfer to bank failed", color = Color.LightGray)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Agree!. creating curves can be done using bezeir curves. But its big topic in itself!.

Comment: @Raghunandan The article you shared is awesome. ✌️

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to draw that arc in a custom composable, I found [this article](https://juliensalvi.medium.com/custom-shape-with-jetpack-compose-1cb48a991d42) that can help you to understand the process of drawing in compose!

Answer (score 0):

turtorial article: https://github.com/JeckOnly/passage/blob/master/Android/Widget/Compose/%E9%A1%B6%E9%83%A8%E5%87%B9%E9%99%B7Shape.md

code:https://gist.github.com/JeckOnly/54936415d1670103a4d400f66c8b31a1

hope this can help you though it is in Chinese language.