# How to draw or create this curve shape in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: canvas, android-jetpack-compose

[image]

I tried using Path and bezier curves concept using cubicTo() method.

I need height 70dp and width 333dp.

```
 @Composable
fun CurveShape() {
    val path = remember { Path() }

    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(80.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color.White)

            //.size(666.dp, 80.dp)
    ) {
        path.reset()
       
        path.cubicTo(x1 = 400f, y1 = 150f, x2 = 500f, y2 = 400f, x3 = size.width, y3 = 00.0f)
   
        drawPath(
            color = Color.Black,
            path = path,
        )
    }
}
```

This is giving me the output like below:

[image]

It is not giving me a propers shape.
Corner shape are not properly shaped.

Please help to achieve this shape in jetpack compose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using two bazier curves would give you the dezired result:

```
Spacer(modifier = Modifier
            .height(80.dp)
            .width(333.dp)
            .background(Color.White)
            .drawWithCache {
                onDrawBehind {
                    val path = Path()
                    path.moveTo(0f, 0f)
                    path.cubicTo(x1 = 333.dp.toPx()/10, y1 = 0f, x2 = 333.dp.toPx()/4, y2 = 70.dp.toPx(), x3 = 333.dp.toPx()/2, y3 = 70.dp.toPx())
                    path.cubicTo(x1 = 333.dp.toPx()*3/4, y1 = 70.dp.toPx(), x2 = 333.dp.toPx()-333.dp.toPx()/10, y2 = 0f, x3 = 333.dp.toPx(), y3 = 0f)
                    drawPath(
                        path = path,
                        color = Color.Black,
                        style = Fill
                    )
                }
            })
```

[image: correspoding image]

With `moveTo()` function we assign the starting point of the bezier curve. The destination points are determined by `(x3,y3)` coordinates.
`(x1,y1)` act as anchor points for the start of the curve and `(x2,y2)` act as anchor points for destination of the curve.

For more details on how these anchor points affect the curve checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73469065/14004940).

Answer (score 2):

**Solution still using Canvas(..)**

You will need to extend the Path out with a secondary `path.cubicTo(..)` call.

Here's a quick and dirty function I've written to generate these cubic curves based on bottomLeft and TopRight values of the curve in the canvas

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CurveShape() {
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(80.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color.White)
    ) {
        drawCubicCurve(
            bottomLeft = Offset(0f, size.height),
            topRight = Offset(size.width, 0f),
            color = Color.Black
        )
    }
}

fun DrawScope.drawCubicCurve(
    bottomLeft: Offset,
    topRight: Offset,
    color: Color = Color.White
) {
    val x1Modifier = 0.41f
    val x2Modifier = 0.22f
    val x3Modifier = 0.5f
    val y1Modifier = 0f
    val y2Modifier = 1f
    val y3Modifier = 1f

    val delta = topRight.minus(bottomLeft)
    val width = delta.x
    val height = delta.y

    val path = Path()
    path.moveTo(bottomLeft.x, bottomLeft.y)
    path.cubicTo(
        x1 = bottomLeft.x.plus(width.times(x1Modifier)),
        y1 = bottomLeft.y.plus(height.times(y1Modifier)),
        x2 = bottomLeft.x.plus(width.times(x2Modifier)),
        y2 = topRight.y.times(y2Modifier),
        x3 = bottomLeft.x.plus(width.times(x3Modifier)),
        y3 = topRight.y.times(y3Modifier),
    )
    path.cubicTo(
        x1 = topRight.x.minus(width.times(x2Modifier)),
        y1 = topRight.y.times(y2Modifier),
        x2 = topRight.x.minus(width.times(x1Modifier)),
        y2 = bottomLeft.y.plus(height.times(y1Modifier)),
        x3 = topRight.x,
        y3 = bottomLeft.y,
    )
    drawPath(
        path = path,
        alpha = 0.5f,
        brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
            colors = listOf(
                color.copy(alpha = 0.0f),
                color.copy(alpha = 0.7f),
                color
            ), startY = bottomLeft.y, endY = topRight.y
        )
    )
    drawPath(
        color = color,
        path = path,
    )
}
```

[image: Curve]

My code draws the curve the other way around as you want it, so I encourage you to play around with the values here to get the resulting curve you want :)

Additionally calling `.reset()` is only required because you have remembered the Path(..). I'd advise you to not remember the Path() as you want to recalculate it whenever a recomposition occurs as the measurements of the Canvas may have changed. Resulting in a different path